# Can i use Jasig CAS server for android mobile applications?

Tags: java, android, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I know that CAS is a single sign-on protocol for the web. Its purpose is to permit a user to access multiple applications while providing their credentials (such as userid and password) only once. It also allows web applications to authenticate users without gaining access to a user's security credentials, such as a password.

So, How can i use Jasig CAS server for android mobile applications ? some guidelines would be very useful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually there exist two ways of doing this, each of them has some drawbacks.

1. Expose the REST interface ([here you'll find a simple JAVA client that consumes them](http://hantri.blogspot.it/2013/09/cas-sample-client-for-java.html) and a [iOS sample](http://hantri.blogspot.it/2013/01/cas-login-from-ios.html) how to use it on a mobile)

The problem here is that if somebody downloads your application from the store and checks the network traffic in it (or simply decomposes it) he'll find the calls you make. With this he could create an APP that does the same as you do, and log the passwords entered by the users (like a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack))

2. Open the real website in a web view inside your APP

You'll need to create a modle login page, or a responsive one on your CAS server so that it looks nice. Obviously even here somebody could theoretically copy your APP and the Website on your CAS fake both to look like your APP grab the username and password and send it in background to your CAS to give to the user the impression that everything went right but it is much more complex.
However even here u'll need to tweak the CAS; CAS is designed to accept a login for a service to which it would redirect after successful login. Therefore in this case you'll need to add a fake service to the CAS configuration and check if the webview will redirect to it. when that happens u'll find the TGT in the CASTGC cookie.

In our first APPs we used the REST version, but then as we use our CAS for websites too we wanted to restrict the REST access only to other servers in the facility, so we came up with the second solution which seems to fit better, but overall CAS seems not to be prepared for mobile APPs

Comment: Thanks! this helped me a lot, but i have a question.
I have the restful api and the oauth configured in my cas server.
So,if i want to combine the restful api with the oauth mechanism, should i create a rest service that uses the oauth mechanism? i'm confused..

Comment: It would works, but consider that with REST exposed, it would be easy to do a brute force attack.

Comment: You're right... actually this system is not really meant to be used by APPs. Everything that you do is just hacking into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up CAS in order to expose REST service, this allow to validate credentials.

Documentation: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/restful+api