# Implement Mobile SSO with Jasig CAS

Tags: android, mobile, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I'm new to Jasig CAS and my task is to implement Mobile SSO for several internal applications of our company and I really need your help on this.

The current status is that my company:

1. Already has a Jasig CAS for SSO of web apps and we would like to customize it for Mobile SSO as well (my senior insists of utilizing this system; rather than implementing other Mobile SSO solutions).
2. We had our own local CA:

   - Every mobile device that is in this system has their device certificate signed by local CA.
   - These device certs can be accessed via a cert database service from server side as well.

What I have in mind is that:

1. For mobile client side (just take Android as default OS): I would like to create a service (Token Agent) that native apps connects to authenticate (sending device cert or encrypted info that can be decrypted from server); receives Authorization Code (or TGT in Jasig CAS' world) and Access Token (Service Ticket)
2. For server side: I would like to customize Jasig CAS so that it can authenticate client; generate Tokens (Tickets) and send them back to Client's Token Agent.

   My current solutions:

   - For client side: I'm implementing a service that consumes RESTful API of Jasig CAS (following these posts: [Can I use Jasig CAS server for Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603477/can-i-use-jasig-cas-server-for-android-mobile-applications) and [Working Java REST Client Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625368/working-java-rest-client-example-to-access-cas-rest-api). Plus, the service has other functions so that native applications can call the service to get/check Authorization Code (TGT) and Access Token (Service Ticket).
   - For server side, I'm confused.
   - What should I do: customizing RESTful API or X509 support module of Jasig CAS.
   - How can I config the address that the client agent will send the request to ... I really hope that someone can help me with my problem, and please be as specific as possible because I'm really new to Jasig CAS. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your requirements. Please refer to the rest of the site to see how your "question" is different from all the others. In short: Show us what you have done, and where, specifically, you are facing problems. This is much to broad.

Comment: Thank you for a quick feedback. What I have done is that I deployed the Jasig CAS to local server. As I followed the post suggesting using RESTFful API, I customized CAS to add REST protocol, I traced Jasig CAS source code to module "Apereo CAS REST Implementation", the TicketsResource.java file for specific. But I don't quite get the meaning of the configuration and the source code. What happens in detailed when my mobile agent sends request with cert info to the URL that I configured, rather than username and password like default?